# Extract information from all matching nodes without looping xpath

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

```
<ul class="products-grid">
    <li class="item">
        <div class="product-block">
            <div class="product-block-inner">
                <a href="#" title="Product A" class="product-image"><img src="#/producta.jpg"></a>
                <h2 class="product-name"><a href="#">Product A</a></h2>
                <div class="price-box">
                    <span class="regular-price" id="#">
                        <span class="price">Rs 1,849</span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <div class="product-block">
            <div class="product-block-inner">
                <a href="#" title="Product B" class="product-image"><img src="#/productb.jpg"></a>
                <h2 class="product-name"><a href="#">Product B</a></h2>
                <div class="price-box">
                    <span class="regular-price" id="#">
                        <span class="price">Rs 1,849</span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I am at this moment scraping the `item` in a loop.

```
products = response.xpath('//ul[@class="products-grid"]//li//div[@class="product-block"]//div[@class="product-block-inner"]').extract()
```

After getting the `product-block-inner` node, I save it into `products` and then I will have to loop like

```
for product in products:
   // parse the div.product-block-inner further deep down
   // to get name, price, image etc
   // and save it to a dict and yeild
   pass
```

Is this possible that i get text, href for all `div.product-block-inner` in the final list without looping

Comment: Why negative marking in this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it's very confusing, for example you could try this:

```
products = response.xpath(
    '//ul[@class="products-grid"]//li//div[@class="product-block"]//div[@class="product-block-inner"]'
).css(
    '.product-name a::attr(href), .product-name a::text, .price::text'
).extract()
```

but I would suggest to always loop (btw, why do you call `extract()` when you assign it to `products`?)

```
products = response.xpath(
    '//ul[@class="products-grid"]//li//div[@class="product-block"]//div[@class="product-block-inner"]'
)
for product in products:
    yield {'name': product.css('.product-name a::text').extract_first()
           'url': product.css('.product-name a::attr(href)').extract_first()
           'price': product.css('.price::text').extract_first()}
```

(I've used css selectors in this case because the equivalent xpaths are longer, but the same can also be achieved using xpath)

Comment: `extract()` is by mistake i pasted. Sorry